# PHPExcell getActiveSheet() not getting all the Columns

Tags: php, phpexcel

When using the PHPExcel IOFactory library, I use the example methods to fetch the active sheet.
But it only returns the first 49 Columns and my Columns go up to 70 Columns.
For some reason it stops at column AW (maybe because that is a date column?)

Some code:

```
/** Include path **/
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'PHPExcel/Classes/');

/** PHPExcel_IOFactory */
include 'PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$inputFileName = $current;
$inputFileType = 'Excel2007';
$sheetname = 'Sheet1';
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$sheetnames = $objReader->listWorksheetNames($inputFileName);
$objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly($sheetnames[0]);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);

$sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true, true, true);
```

Screenshot of my XLS file :

[image: xls file headings]

Screenshot of my Debugger:

[image]

Comment: Does it work if `AX` is not empty? I think PHPExcel "thinks" there are no more columns after `AW` because the next one is empty.

Comment: Doesn't make a difference if there is something in AX. When I calll $getHighestColumn = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex()->getHighestColumn(); I still get AW as the highest column. Is there a limitation in PHPExcell?

Comment: I think i've seen some kind of limitation, but it was all the way up to BY or more if i remember correctly, but i'm not sure. At least it won't be AX ^^

Comment: I see there is a 256 limitation, so I created a blank xlsx sheet and ran the same code. Now my highest column is BZ as expected. Which means there is something going on with my original xls to be imported. Doesn't look like a page break or anything... any ideas?

Comment: It seems the sheet is broken... Have you tried to create a blank xls (not xlsx) sheet and ran it again?

Comment: There is no limitation on columns or rows of any kind in PHPExcel that isn't actually an MS Excel or a PHP limitation

Answer (score 0):

Ok seems like my XLS file is corrupted. If I try and run an Excel Open and Repair... and I extract all the values, then it only extracts the values up to column AW

**Some More Info:** The xlsm file was generated using VB code to fill all the data after column AW. So there must be something extra that prevents PHPExcell from reading those fields